# Is there a lightweight way to embed a YouTube video in a website?

Tags: html, performance, youtube

The base YouTube JS file adds 500Kb to your website, slowing down load time.

[image]

(Image source: https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/)

How can we speed up page load time, while keeping YouTube videos embedded?

Answer (score 0):

A great solution worth sharing on StackOverflow:

- https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/